# How to assemble dictionary out of multiple list with if/elif/else using list comprehension

Tags: python

With three list variables (all different sizes) and a list comprehension:

```
indexesA=[1,2,3,4,5]
indexesB=['a','b','c','d']
values=['Dog','Cat','Sheep','Donkey','Horse']

keys=[2,3,'d']    
print [values[indexesA.index(key)] for key in keys if key in indexesA and indexesA.index(key)<len(values)]
```

I need to get a dictionary:

```
{2: 'Cat', 3: 'Sheep', 'd': 'Donkey'}
```

`indexesA` list should be checked if `key` among its values first. If not then check `indexesB`.
How to achieve this?

## Edited:

Please note that the list comprehension I posted in my question is only checking `indexesA` for the key. The code is incomplete.

```
print [values[indexesA.index(key)] for key in keys if key in indexesA and indexesA.index(key)<len(values)]
```

Comment: Your output example does not make sense given the input and discussion - keys S/B [2,3,'d'] to get your output

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it using `list-comprehensions`

```
>>> keys = [2, 3, 'd']
>>> {k: values[indexesA.index(k) if k in indexesA else indexesB.index(k)] for k in keys if (k in indexesA) or (k in indexesB)}
{2: 'Cat', 3: 'Sheep', 'd': 'Donkey'}
>>>
```

Disclaimer: This code is neither readable, maintainable or extendable.

Comment: See the output ? The 4th index of the `values` list is `Donkey`, and your sample output dictionary says `Sheep` . It is a minor mistake

Comment: Great. Just one thing - I would try to avoid overusing list/dict comprehensions like in this usecase. It is sometimes worth keeping the code readable, and maintainable. Example, if tomorrow there is a 3rd array called `indexesC`, the code should accommodate it..

Comment: The code execution speed matters to me more than readability. But thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: @Sputnix Profile your code then, the list comprehension isn't necessarily faster. I tried a for loop to do the same thing and it was faster than this solution, perhaps because the key's existence in indexesA is being tested twice.